# Pythagoras Theorem or Trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

**I had this question in my test:-**
Authority wants to construct a slide in a city park for children. Authority prefers the top of the slide at a height of 4m above the ground and inclined at an angle of 30° with the ground.

So one of the subparts of this question was:-
If AB + BC = 25m and AC = 5m, then the value of BC is:-
(A) 25m      (B) 15m
(C) 10m      (D) 12m

**Actual solution:**

So the solution was by assuming BC = x and AB = 25 - x. Then by applying Pythagoras Theroem we have:
$(25-x)^2 = x^2 + 5^2$ and then after solving for x we get x = BC = 12m

**My Approach:**
I applied sine for angle B :
$\sin(B) = \sin(30°) = \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{AC}{AB} = \dfrac{5}{AB} \\ \implies AB = 10m$

Then by using the relation: $AB + BC = 25m$, I got $BC = 15m.$

**My Problems:**

1. Why do the two answers differ?
2. In the way I solved, the sides are: 5, 10 and 15, which is not a Pythagoream Triplet. How is this possible since the slide should be perpendicular to the ground, and even more, trigonometric ratios exist for right triangles only.
3. In my answer why is the side BC which is a leg has more length than the hypotenuse AB

[image]

Comment: The angle with the ground in the second case is not $30^\circ$ but when you are applying law of sines, you are assuming angle to be $30^\circ$ which for the given length constraints does not give a right triangle.

Comment: You may want to fix the subpart since we are solving for $AC$, yet $AC$ is already given as $5\,\mathrm{cm}$.

Comment: can you provide a photo of the whole question (not just the slide photo) because there is so much wrong in this

Comment: I guess Math Lover is right : the subpart does not say that the triangle is right angle triangle, so you can't use the formula of sine because this formula is only applied in the right angle triangle case and when yku used it you actually assumed that the triangle is right angle which is not, so the only way i guess is to use the actual solution

Comment: What do $A,B,C$ have to do with the slide in the city park?

Comment: What is $A$, $B$ and $C$? Please provide the full problem (and also fix the typo in the subpart).

Comment: I love it when questions approximate a random curved slide to perfect trigonometry; just like frictionless physics.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I am sorry the subpart asks for BC not AC, and also the units would be in m not cm. I am unable to edit anymore because the "edit" option has gone 

Comment: Thanks, got it @Math Lover and others also. I wish I could tag all to thank them but it's not letting me do it

Comment: Can you give the *whole* question. Then we can find out if there is an error in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever wrote the "test" was not thinking clearly enough about trigonometry and the Pythagorean theorem.
The $\textbf{Actual solution}$ suggests
$\quad (25-x)^2 = x^2 + 5^2
\implies 600-50x=0
\implies x=12\quad$ but, with $\angle ABC=30^\circ,\space$ none of the sides are integer multipls of $3$ or $5$.

The first paragraph and the picture describe  half of an equilateral triangle and $\textit{that}$ half has dimensions of
$(4\sqrt{3},4,8)\approx (6.93,\space 4,\space 8) $
where $4\sqrt{3}$ is the "altitude" <sarcasm>  or the $x$-axis running along the ground.

This means it is not a Pythagorean triple where all sides are integers. The Pythagorean theorem does apply in

$$BC^2+AC^2=AB^2\\
(4\sqrt{3})^2+4^2=8^2$$